# HTML Coding. Can you use <a href> within a 'li' (list)?

Tags: html

I am quite new to using HTML coding. Basically, when i try to link my pages together via . If you can look at my coding, and please try and help me somehow, that would be great.

```
<html> 

<head>
<title> Information about Birmingham </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css" />

<link rel="style" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="Header">

    <h1> Information|Birmingham  </h1>

</div>

<div id="Nav">

<h2>

<ul style="list-style-type:none">
<li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Shopping.html">Shopping</a></li>
<li><a href="Arts">Art</a></li> 
<li><a href="Food">Food</a></li> 
<li><a href="Nightlife">Nightlife</a></li>

</h2>
```

Comment: Yes you can https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li Please do some research before posting

Comment: To answer your question, yes you can place links within a list. However, what is the issue you're having? You don't seem to specify in your question.

Comment: try help with what ?

Comment: I'd suggest you delete this question, as it's not going to be very helpful on here. You're answer is 'Yes' you can, it's a very standard method to use list items for.

Comment: Hey everyone. This is now sorted! Simple mistake on my behalf. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The href tag to point to the html file you'd like to link to. If you home file is index.html it should be `<a href="index.html">Home</a>`

The others would be something like this:

```
<li><a href="Shopping.html">Shopping</a></li>
<li><a href="Arts.html">Art</a></li> 
<li><a href="Food.html">Food</a></li> 
<li><a href="Nightlife.html">Nightlife</a></li>
```

Just keep in mind that these need to point to html files that are in your root directory.

Comment: Congrats for understanding the question. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, make sure the html files are in the `same directory` as the page you're looking at, `it might not be the root but it must be the same`.

Answer (score 0):

Your links must include the full file name "i.e home.html rather than home" and you should also make sure that the files of the other pages are in the same directory as the current page for that to work.

Another problem in your code is that you forgot to close the `<ul>` tag. You must add `</ul>` just before `</h2>`.

Also, it is not recommended that you place your list inside a heading tag `<h2>` in your case. If you are doing this for styling reasons you should better use csss to style your list.